# Requesting JWT's from ADFS 3/OAUTH2 to Access Web API Resources

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, adfs, jwt

I have the following architecture in place:

MVC Website <--> Web API

JS/Mobile-app/etc <--> Web API (same Web API as above)

ADFS 3.0

- 1 - Client users of the MVC website will authenticate using WS-Federation in ADFS 3.0. Logins are handled through the ACS login screen.
- 2 - Direct Usage of WebAPI

  - 2a - Clients that attempt to access the Web API directly (from JS, or perhaps a mobile app) will also authenticate through the ACS login screen. This is setup in the Web API's authorization server (OWIN middleware)? Once authenticated, clients can access resources from the Web API.
  - 2b - The MVC website attempts to access resources from the Web API. The client users are already authenticated (SSO via ADFS). We'll still need to request a JWT to present to the Web API (by sending it in the request 'Authorization' header), then validate the JWT on the Web API side.

My question really centers around 2b. I could request the token, in C#, and follow the redirects, but this sounds difficult, and I've seen zero examples of this coded-out online. I have seen examples where clients open a `WSTrustChannelFactory` and have a `RST` issued to them (I've done this, but I'm unable to actually get a JWT, just a `GenericXmlToken` instead).

I am most interested in the strategy I should attempt to have the JWT issued for the Web API, that can be presented to the Web API, for my MVC client users.

Comment: to my understanding you are have a Token endpoint in your api which you call get the token and then use that token to make a call to any other endpoint in web api  and you are looking for a simple way of doing that ? is that what you are looking for.

Comment: @Prashant - yes that's essentially what I am looking for. My concern however is that ADFS is the issuer, not the Web API itself... because ADFS will be issuing the claims. And I haven't really seen any examples of this. Of course, my understanding could be way off...

Comment: If you have not yet explored "DelegatingHandler" implementation for authentication you should look at it once. I have a similar setup where i token endpoint which gives as a oauth bearer token and then i use that token to call any other endpoint. I am thinking your requirement is similar.

 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/16/extending-httpclient-with-oauth-to-access-twitter.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/630986/Cross-Platform-Authentication-With-ASP-NET-Web-API

try looking at these links a little and see if it makes sense to you.